# how to connect mongosqld externally

Tags: mongodb, odbc

I'm using mongoDB in linux with BI connector(mongosqld)

mongosqld works well and it can be accessed from the local.

but it is not accessible from the external. (windows with mongodbODBC driver)

with Can't connect to MySQL server on 'server address' (10061)

Maybe external access is not possible. How do we fix it?

(port is open.)

Comment: Hello, were you able to fix it?

Comment: nope.........TT